# ASCII Code Of Characters

Tags: c#, char, byte

In C# I need to get the ASCII code of some characters. 
So I convert the `char` To `byte` Or `int`, then print the result.

```
String sample="A";
int AsciiInt = sample[0];
byte AsciiByte = (byte)sample[0];
```

For characters with ASCII code 128 and less, I get the right answer.
But for characters greater than 128 I get irrelevant answers!

I am sure all characters are less than 0xFF.

Also I have Tested `System.Text.Encoding` and got the same results.

For example: I get 172 For a char with actual byte value of 129!

Actually ASCII characters Like **ƒ , ‡ , ‹ , “ , ¥ , © , Ï , ³ , · , ½ , » , Á**
  Each character takes 1 byte and goes up to more than 193. 
I Guess There is An Unicode Equivalent for Them and .Net Return That Because Interprets Strings As Unicode!
What If SomeOne Needs To Access The Actual Value of a byte , Whether It is a valid Known ASCII Character Or Not!!!

Comment: Which character do you believe to have an "actual byte value of 129"?

Comment: (And how did you obtain such a character?)

Comment: I Updated My Question,It seems .net doesnt recognize them!!I open Files Written with these chars using VS Binary Editor And I see The Actual Bytes.

Comment: You updated your question with a fairly vague description. It seems to me that the problem is with your use of this font, not .NET. I believe Unicode supports Farsi characters, and both your font and your code should be using those characters... none of which have UTF-16 code units less than 256...

Comment: @JonSkeet , i Have No Problem using Unicode Farsi Which Is the Normal Formatting. But These Fonts I Talk About Are Different.They Assign Just 1 Byte For Each Character,That is Not Unicode,Right?And We Use Them To Read/Write Farsi in Environments Not Supporting Unicode, Like Unity3D GameEngine.

Comment: Well it depends on what the font is doing - but we really don't have any information about that. Fundamentally, .NET handles text as Unicode, so you need to know how the font interacts with that. If it's treating some Unicode characters as if they were other characters, that's frankly pretty nasty IMO, but manageable... but you at least need to understand what's going on. We *still* don't know what you mean by "I get 172 for a char with actual byte value of 129." If the problem is with the file encoding, that's different... we don't know how the file was written or how you're reading it.

Comment: Thanks Jon For Attention, Lets Simplify Question.The Problem is This Character ƒ. which is 0x83 or 131, when I cast to int as mentioned above I get 402!!! It Might Have Unicode Equivalent of 402,But Try saving a byte in a text file with value of 131 , when opening the file you see ƒ

Comment: "But Try saving a byte in a text file with value of 131 , when opening the file you see ƒ" - that entirely depends on what encoding you're using. I think you've fundamentally not understood encodings. See if http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx helps - and note the edit to my answer... I suspect you just want to use ISO-8859-1 as the encoding.

Comment: That shift key really has it in for you huh..

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes Your Right,I confused ASCII,ANSI ... and encodings.I took a Break,Read your Book Chapter and Descriptions Here.And I Got it Solved.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But For Characters Upper Than 128 I get Irrelevant answers

No you don't. You get the bottom 8 bits of the UTF-16 code unit corresponding to the `char`.

Now if your text were all ASCII, that would be fine - because ASCII only goes up to 127 anyway. It sounds like you're *actually* expecting the representation in some other encoding - so you need to work out which encoding that is, at which point you can use:

```
Encoding encoding = ...;
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(sample);
// Now extract the bytes you want. Note that a character may be represented by more than
// one byte.
```

If you're essentially looking for an encoding which treats bytes 0 to 255 respectively as U+0000 to U+00FF respectively, you should use ISO-8859-1, which you can access using `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)`.

Comment: Actually I am Working With Characters Used In Special Font Family, That represent Farsi Language , Each Character Takes 1 byte and goes up to more than 193.

Comment: @hamednaseri: Then that's certainly *not* ASCII, and you need to work out which encoding you're actually using. (Unicode doesn't contain any Farsi characters in the range U+0000 to U+00FF as far as I'm aware, so I think you need to look at this pretty carefully... it's possible that your font is actually just providing glyphs for entirely different Unicode characters...)

Comment: Yes It was not ASCII, I used to save characters in NotePad with ANSI (1 byte for each character). Then I opened The Bytes Assuming each Byte Value Is its ASCII Code!!! trivial Mistake.Thanks for your descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just ignore the issue of encoding. There is no inherent mapping between bytes and characters - that's defined by the encoding.

If I use your example of 131, on my system, this produces `â`. However, since you're obviously on an arabic system, you most likely have Windows-1256 encoding, which produces `ƒ` for 131.

In other words, if you need to use the correct encoding when converting characters to bytes and vice versa. In your case,

```
var sample = "ƒ";
var byteValue = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetBytes(sample)[0];
```

Which produces 131, as you seem to expect. Most importantly, this will work on all computers - if you want to have this system locale-specific, `Encoding.Default` can also work for you.

The only reason your method seems to work for bytes under 128 is that in UTF-8, the characters correspond to the ASCII standard mapping. However, you're misusing the term ASCII - it really only refers to these 7-bit characters. What you're calling ASCII is actually an extended 8-bit charset - all characters with the 8-bit set are charset-dependent.

We're no longer in a world when you can assume your application will only run on computers with the same locale you have - .NET is designed for this, which is why all strings are unicode. At the very least, read this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html for an explanation of how encodings work, and to get rid of some of the serious and dangerous misconceptions you seem to have.

Comment: Great Explanation, and good Article, I Had several MisUnderstandings About Unicode and Encodings.